# How to make MSBuild to automatically copy all indirect references to output (bin) folder

Tags: .net, msbuild, build-automation, dependencies, reference

Subj.

"Automatically" is essential here. References from GAC must not be copied.

I've seen e.g. [VS2008.NET: Getting a referenced project’s dependencies to copy to main project’s bin folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634365/vs2008-net-getting-a-referenced-projects-dependencies-to-copy-to-main-projects), and this isn't interesting for me. I'd like all the dependencies get  copied automatically.

Comment: Fortunately, I answered this question by my own. If you're interested, [the solution is here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180805184435/http://blog.alexyakunin.com:80/2009/09/making-msbuild-visual-studio-to.html).

Comment: It'll be useful if in addition to your blog, you'll post it here as an answer and accept it as well.

Answer (score 1):

For C++ projects, i.e. *.vcxproj set the `<OutDir>` property.

for C# projects, i.e. *.csproj set the `<OutputPath>` property.

Make sure nothing overwrites those properties. In all my years doing builds for major, large products, I've never had to do anything different. If you have to do any other clever hack, you are surely doing something wrong.

Answer (score -1):

use post build event

**EDIT**

```
XCOPY c:/additionlib $(OutDir)
```

Comment: There are a lot of perf issues with such a Postbuild event there are better option that use a custom target that specifies an inputs attribute to prevent msbuild from copying files over and over again.

Comment: Right. Do not ever use post build events. In the last 10 years, I have always deleted post build events when-ever I have found them, and replaced them with real msbuild targets.