# How to configure msbuild/MSVC to deploy dependent files of dependent assemblies

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, dependencies

I have a dependency chain that looks like this (simplification for example purposes):

application
    -> foo (contains foo.dll)
       -> bar (contains bar.dll and bar_data.xml)

the dependent files are correctly marked with "copy if newer" on the data file and "copy local" on the references.

- bar/bin/Debug correctly contains bar.dll and bar_data.xml
- foo/bin/Debug correctly contains foo.dll, bar.dll and bar_data.xml
- application/bin/Debug only contains foo.dll and bar.dll (and app.exe), but not bar_data.xml

If I make application dependent on foo and bar, then I correctly get all three files.

I haven't found anything on either msdn or stackoverflow that covers this case.

[MSBuild doesn't pick up references of the referenced project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137229/msbuild-doesnt-pick-up-references-of-the-referenced-project) - doesn't work if you have a directed graph of dependencies rather than a tree (app links to foo and baz which both link to bar).

[How to make MSBuild to automatically copy all indirect references to output (bin) folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425359/how-to-make-msbuild-to-automatically-copy-all-indirect-references-to-output-bin) and [/LinkResource in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625129/linkresource-in-visual-studio-2010) - only work on ".pdb" and ".xml" files that have the exact same name as the project, though [Alex's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106042/alex-yakunin)'s example seems to be closer to what I need.

edit:

Marking the files to deploy (baz_data.xml) as "linkresource" works if you want the files in exactly the same location as the dll.

In my case I want them in a subdirectory due to the deploy environment.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Comment: At $work we ended up either adding direct references to the indirect libraries, or creating separate projects with just the data and referencing those (depending on the library). So no good solution.