# Copy project artifacts to bin folder on successful build event batch file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, batch-file, post-build-event

I'd like to copy project files and folders to the bin\debug folder on successful build.
I'm trying to get xcopy to do it, but it either copies 0 files or tells me it can't copy cyclicly.
What I'm trying to do is similar to this [question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634365/vs2008-net-getting-a-referenced-projects-dependencies-to-copy-to-main-projects)
Here's my batch file:

```
@echo off

REM Set up the files and folders to exclude
echo \bin\ > exclude.txt
echo exclude.txt >> exclude.txt
echo Helper.cs >> exclude.txt
echo Program.cs >> exclude.txt

REM Set up the variables
set sourceBase="D:\Devprojects\WebApplications\GenerateTabbedHTML"
set destinationBase="D:\Devprojects\WebApplications\GenerateTabbedHTML\bin\Debug\"
set params=/E /C /I /R /Y /Exclude:exclude.txt

xcopy %sourceBase% %destinationBase% %params%
```

Am I going about this the right way?  Or is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `xcopy` doesn't like the fact that your dest folder is inside your source folder. You do exclude it, but I guess it can't handle the situation anyway. Try using an intermediate folder, which is not under the source. Have the files first copied there, and then to the target.

Comment: I've got bin folder in the exclude text, but I'll give the intermediate folder a shot.  Thanks!